# setvbuf not able to make stdin unbuffered

Tags: c, buffer, stdin, getchar, unbuffered

My main intention was to make `getchar` return as soon as it gets a character instead of waiting for the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. I tried this

```
int main()
{
    setvbuf(stdin,NULL,_IONBF,0);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comparing this with the prototype of `setvbuf`

```
setvbuf ( FILE * stream, char * buffer, int mode, size_t size );
```

it should set `stdin` to unbuffered mode.

But still `getchar()` keeps waiting for <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

I've seen related posts like this

[Printing while reading characters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228902/printing-while-reading-characters-in-c/10229044#10229044)

which are suggesting alternate methods to make `stdin` unbuffered. But I am curious to know as to why `setvbuf` method does not work

Comment: You must call `setvbuf()` before any "movement" on the stream ... so first thing in `main()`.

Comment: @pmg I updated my post to reflect what I tried. But still it doesn't work

Comment: I think the problem is not with `setvbuf()`. I tried your program with and without `setvbuf()` and the behaviour is different. Without `setvbuf()` all characters up to and including the ENTER are consumed (even though it is consumed only after typing ENTER); with `setvbuf()` only the first character is consumed, the remaining characters are used as a following bash command.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The terminal driver doesn't return anything until you hit return, even if the `read()` operation would accept what's already there.

To get character-by-character input from a terminal, you have to get it out of canonical mode into raw or cbreak mode, and that requires different operations altogether.  Take a look at the POSIX manual on ['General Terminal Interface'](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11) for how to control the terminal.  Or consider using the `curses` library.

See also: [Canonical vs non-canonical terminal input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/canonical-vs-non-canonical-terminal-input/358381#358381)

Comment: `setvbuf(stdin,NULL,_IONBF,0);` is supposed to do that right? I mean `setvbuf` works fine for all file pointers but not for `stdin`?

Comment: No.  `setvbuf()` just tells the standard I/O library in your program to use no buffer; it doesn't tell the terminal driver anything.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are trying this under Linux or another Unix-like system, it is the terminal that buffers the input and only passes an entire line. You can use ncurses to circumvent this:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -o main main.c -lncurses
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw these alternate methods, but I was curious as to why `setvbuf` doesn't work