# Scanning text forces me to go in next line, to confirm input. Can I prevent this for a special case?

Tags: c, cursor, scanf

So basically I have a a program in C, whose point is to look organized.
I'd like my program's cursor not to move after I confirm my Scanf statement.
Heres example part of my program and its output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char input[10];
int voltage=220;
printf("What do you want to know\n");      //no need to correct me on this part please
scanf("%s", input);
if (strcmp("voltage",input)==0)
     printf(" = %d\n", voltage);
/* Imagine other string comparisons (resistance, current) here*/
return 0;
}
```

So this program for input "voltage" would output something like this:
voltage //what I just inputed via scanf
 = 220 // \n because I pressed enter after inputing.

What I wanted is:

voltage = 220

I dont know Is there reverse \n function that I dont know about.

Comment: How about removing `\n` from `printf()` in the first call?

Comment: That wouldnt help at all. I end input with new line, but I dont want that. The \n you were talking about hasnt got anything to do with the whole problem

Comment: Somewhat harsh on @Filipe Gonçalves.  It is amazing how seemingly irrelevant issues do affect the end results.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247591/setvbuf-not-able-to-make-stdin-unbuffered

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry about that, but my other account is disabled, for asking noob-ish questions, but they were still on higher level than his answer was. Idk.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way in C to read input without pressing Enter. You will have to go for platform specific functions.

There are lots of questions here in StackOverflow that cover this, such as [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr)

Comment: So theres not much I can do? well thank you anyways sir.

Comment: @user3272749 Well, there is, it just might not be as easy as you thought it would. As I said, you have to use platform specific solutions. If you only want this to work on linux, try the curses library.