# Unbuffered non-blocking keyboard input on command line

Tags: python, stdin, nonblocking

I want to capture "all" keyboard input on the command line ***immediately*** (without waiting for a new line) in a ***non-blocking*** way.

[**This question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-detect-a-keypress-in-python/1450063#1450063) demonstrates how you can read from `stdin` in a non-blocking way using `select()`. This is how it works:

```
while True:
    if select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0] == [sys.stdin]:
        print(sys.stdin.read(1))

    ... do other stuff ...
```

Unfortunately you only get results after pressing <kbd>`RETURN`</kbd>.

My first guess was that `stdin` is just line buffered so after reading [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670323/setting-smaller-buffer-size-for-sys-stdin) I turned my code into

```
ubuf_stdin = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', buffering=0)
while True:
    if select.select([ubuf_stdin], [], [], 0)[0] == [ubuf_stdin]:
        print(ubuf_stdin.read(1))
    ... do other stuff ...
```

This code works better - the buffer is being read completely without interruptions - but it still waits for <kbd>`RETURN`</kbd> being pressed.

I also tried to `detach` `stdin`:

```
ubuf_stdin = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.detach().fileno(), 'rb', buffering=0)
```

How do I react on keyboard input **immediately** after a key press?

Comment: The answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247591/setvbuf-not-able-to-make-stdin-unbuffered) suggests it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getch` module to get a single keypress at a time, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175964/python-method-for-reading-keypress).

I don't think you'll be able to read stdin in a non-blocking-yet-character-at-a-time way, it's really not intended for that purpose.

Comment: Well - that can't be the whole truth - at least `ncurses` (which is available on POSIX as well as on Windows) can read from `stdin` character wise..

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ncurses` and its variants are using /dev/tty or the equivalent, not the actual stdin file descriptor. I could be totally speaking out my ass, too.

Comment: Ok, maybe you're right - I have to change my title. What I really want is capture keyboard input in a command line program. `stdin` was just the first thing to come into my mind :)

Comment: Then `getch` is probably your best bet.

Comment: but `getch` blocks, doesn't it? The advantage is that with `getch` you don't see the characters on the screen but you would have to either start a thread or somehow `select()` the terminal device..

Comment: Yes, but it blocks for a single keypress, so the idea is to just loop forever, and start each loop with a `getch`, and then do something based on that keypress: call a function, buffer it into a sequence of keystrokes, etc. See the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12179724/2926055).

Answer (score 0):

Ok this one does it but it has some disadvantages yet:

- uses the `curses` module which seems a bit heavy to me
- input has to be polled - no way to `select()` yet.
- the keyboard input still gets printed to the terminal

.. but it works :).

```
import curses
def read_stdin(self):
    def cb(screen):
        result = []
        screen.nodelay(1)
        while True:
            try:
                result.append(screen.getkey())
            except curses.error:
                return result

    # contains a list of keys pressed since last call
    return curses.wrapper(cb)
```