# C - Reading one character at a time from stdin in a large string

Tags: c, input, formatting

I want to read one character at a time from standard input and operate on that. For example, input

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

What I want is, to operate on `a` (which is the first character) as soon as it has been entered (the operation on `a` should be done before the user enters `b`) and then operate on `b` and so on.

Comment: So you want to work in non-canonical mode, take a look to [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) on unixes or [conio](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h) on windoses :)

Comment: Also you can take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247591/setvbuf-not-able-to-make-stdin-unbuffered

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this other solution.

Taken from https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Noncanon-Example.html and https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_17.html.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>

/* Use this variable to remember original terminal attributes. */

struct termios saved_attributes;

void
reset_input_mode (void)
{
  tcsetattr (STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &saved_attributes);
}

void
set_input_mode (void)
{
  struct termios tattr;
  char *name;

  /* Make sure stdin is a terminal. */
  if (!isatty (STDIN_FILENO))
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Not a terminal.\n");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  /* Save the terminal attributes so we can restore them later. */
  tcgetattr (STDIN_FILENO, &saved_attributes);
  atexit (reset_input_mode);

  /* Set the funny terminal modes. */
  tcgetattr (STDIN_FILENO, &tattr);
  tattr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO); /* Clear ICANON and ECHO. */
  tattr.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
  tattr.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
  tcsetattr (STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &tattr);
}


int
main (void)
{
  char c;

  set_input_mode ();

  while (1)
    {
      read (STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
      if (c == '\004')          /* C-d */
        break;
      else
        putchar (c);
    }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This could be an answer but we don't know his OS, also, you should put the _Save the terminal attributes so we can restore them later_ part in `main` (at the very begin) instead of calling it each time a key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int c;
  puts ("Enter text");
  do {
    c = getchar();
    putchar (c); //do whatever you want with this character.
  } while (c != '\0');

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I suspect that OP wants to see those changes before pressing Enter.

Comment: Yes. I want to operate on the input before pressing enter. The operation should start as soon as the character has been entered.

Comment: @bigcoder, Luis Daniel's code does exactly that, but those changes are non visible until you press enter because your terminal is working in canonical mode, `getch` (not standard) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify an operating system, I am going to give a suggestion suitable for the windows operating system.

The function `GetAsyncKeyState()` does exactly what you ask for. You can read its documentation from [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx).

As a quick example on its usage:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    while(1) {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState('A') & 0x8000) {
            /* code goes here */
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```