# How to define a certain time for the getch() function in C?

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks, getch

I am trying to have the function getch() of the C language in Windows to work only for a few seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    int v1, v2;
    v1=getch();//I want this getch to only be activated for a few seconds
    printf("Example");//That to activate the next function, even if the person reading this programm doesn't click in any key
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you make `stdin` unbuffered? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247591/setvbuf-not-able-to-make-stdin-unbuffered

Comment: @FiddlingBits not really related to what OP is asking for.

Comment: Windows - you can check `kbhit()` in a timeout loop - say using `clock()`. No special steps are needed, it is provided for you so you don't have to commit to the blocking function

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I wasn't clear.  What I meant was you can spin in a loop and `break` when time has expired.  The problem with `getch` (`stdin`) is that it blocks by default, right?

Comment: @FiddlingBits exactly, it's not "by default", it just blocks if there's no data available, that's it.

Comment: @FiddlingBits `getch` isn't `stdin`. It can't be redirected.

Comment: @WeatherVane  You should make an answer.

Comment: The answer is no, you cannot timeout a call to getch(). You have to think of a different way to attain your goal.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kbhit()` which tests if a key has been pressed, before committing to the blocking function `getch()`. The loop below uses `clock()` to check for timeout.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TIMEOUT 5   // seconds

int main(void)
{
    clock_t tstart = clock();
    int v1 = 'y';                   // default key press
    while((clock() - tstart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC < TIMEOUT) {
        if(kbhit()) {
            v1 = getch();
            break;
        }
    }
    if(tolower(v1) == 'y')
        printf("Example\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It's particularly useful in a game, where you don't want to sit there waiting for a key press, and then it isn't quite so simple to use. When you press a function key or a cursor key `getch()` returns two successive characters, the first is an "escape" value which must be checked for.

Comment: Note: it is recommended to use  '_kbhit' and '_getch' instead of 'kbhit'  and 'getch' on windows: 
'C4996 'kbhit': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _kbhit. See online help for details. 
'

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the ncurse library and call:

- **initscr** or **newterm** to initialize the screen
- **timeout** with a positive delay. Otherwise, it will not be blocking.

Read more [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/curs_inopts/)